# What is the mocking framework of choice in Unit Test Library for Windows Store Applications?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, windows-8

When I write unit tests I like to use Rhino Mocks.

So when I started my first Windows Store application I naturally started with my unit tests first.  When I tried to add [RhinoMocks](http://ayende.com/blog/tags/rhino-mocks) via [NuGet](https://nuget.org/) I recieved the following error

> Could not install package 'RhinoMocks 3.6.1'. You are trying to
>   install this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETCore,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly
>   references that are compatible with that framework. For more
>   information, contact the package author.

I had the same issue with Moq.

Is there a mocking framework for .NETCor,Version=v4.5?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most mocking frameworks are based on `Reflection.Emit`.  Unfortunately `Reflection.Emit` isn't in WinRT.  This means you can't do dynamic proxies. (I.e. Run-time mocking). This leaves pre-generation of mocks that get referenced at compile-time.  The only framework I know of is an experimental branch of Moq: https://github.com/mbrit/moqrt

Answer (score 2):

I made this for use with Windows Phone 7, should work with Win 8 as it's just a post build step:

http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Introducing-%28probably%29-The-Worlds-Only-Mocking-Framework-for-Windows-Phone-7-%28WP7%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here are my suggestions, be aware I haven't tested any of these myself yet.  [Here](http://www.richonsoftware.com/post/2012/04/05/Using-Stubs-and-Shim-to-Test-with-Microsoft-Fakes-in-Visual-Studio-11.aspx) is a link to an article discussing the first two options.

1. TypeMock Isolator - expensive, but looks like it would do the job
2. Microsoft Fakes (evolved from a project at MSR called Moles)
3. Instead of mocking (or doing dependency injection), you could use a different technique.   You could use parameterized injection and just pass in the information you need to test.  This reduces to large objects to delegates and primitives, relieving the need for a mocking framework. [Here](http://arlobelshee.com/post/easily-eliminate-most-mocks) is more about this, including an [example](http://blog.approvaltests.com/2012/03/testing-difficult-code.html) of the technique in action.

Comment: Microsoft Fakes is not available from WinRT

Comment: Isolator is not available for winRT apps

Answer (score 0):

Actually, [Philipp Dolder](https://twitter.com/philippdolder), one of the contributors to [FakeItEasy](https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy) has come up with an interesting and working approach based on Portable Class Libraries.
http://www.planetgeek.ch/2013/02/01/fakeiteasy-and-windows-store-apps-are-becoming-friends/

In essence, he proposes the following solution:

1. Put all your productive code that will be TDD-ed into a PCL class library where you select whatever target frameworks you like to support
2. Create your test assembly as a regular class library
3. Add the references to FakeItEasy and your test framework(s) of choice (e.g. NUnit + FluentAssertions) to your *.Test assembly
4. Only put the UI stuff that you can’t test into a Windows Store App project

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

I know the original question is old but there are many of us still out there trying to accomplish mocking in Windows Store Apps.

I have recently started to use [MoqaLate](https://moqalate.codeplex.com/) which states: Mocking for Windows Phone & Windows Store apps.
It actually physically creates the MockingClasses after you Build your solution.
So, after build you will have a folder with some Mock implementation of your classes.

I think is not the best option. Run-time mocking will be the ideal but in the meantime it creates the mocks for me.