# Unit Testing MVVMLight Messenger

Tags: nunit, mvvm-light

Is it possible to write a Unit Test that calls the Messenger.Default.Register method and then write an Assertion to be used by the Action?

I would like to determine if my ViewModel is sending the correct message after calling an Execute on one of my Commands.

I have tried writing the Assert.AreEqual as the Action however this doesn't seem to be working correctly.

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like a job for [mocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object)!  Assuming you're passing in the messenger interface to your viewmodel (because [dependency inversion is a Good Thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29), for this very reason), your code should look *something* like this if I understand you correctly:

```cs
public class YourViewModel
{
    readonly IMessenger messenger;

    public YourViewModel(IMessenger messenger)
    {
        this.messenger = messenger;
        // setup of your delegate command to call Execute
    }

    void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        messenger.Send(new YourMessageType());
    }
}
```

Then in your unit test you'd mock the messenger and verify that the right method is called, which in this case is `Send`.  So, using the popular mocking framework [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4):

```cs
public class YourViewModelTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Execute_Always_SendsYourMessageType()
    {
        // arrange
        var mockRepository = new MockRepository(MockBehavior.Loose);
        var mockMessenger = mockRepository.Create<IMessenger>();
        var systemUnderTest = new YourViewModel(mockMessenger.Object);

        // act
        systemUnderTest.YourCommand.Execute(null);

        // assert
        mockMessenger.Verify(p => p.Send<YourMessageType>(
                          It.Is(m => /* return true if it's the right message */)));
    }
}
```

Usually I'd move the just about all of the "arrange" phase into a test setup method, but you should get the idea.

---

If you'd still like to do it without mocking the messenger and also use `Messenger.Default`, you can do the following:

```cs
public class YourViewModelTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Execute_Always_SendsYourMessageType()
    {
        // arrange
        var systemUnderTest = new YourViewModel();

        // Set the action to store the message that was sent
        YourMessageType actual;
        Messenger.Default.Register<YourMessageType>(this, t => actual = t);


        // act
        systemUnderTest.YourCommand.Execute(null);


        // assert
        YourMessageType expected = /* set up your expected message */;
        Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Is there a way to achieve the same either without using mocking or with a mocking library that works with a PCL?

Comment: @PaulDiston Ah that changes things a bit.  See my edit, and also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12083462/what-is-the-mocking-framework-of-choice-in-unit-test-library-for-windows-store-a) for mocks and PCL compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, for each test it is possible to create a separate copy of the Messenger. For the runtime you want to use the Default instance of the Messenger, but for Unit Tests, as I said, create a separate copy for each test:

```
        return new GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger(); // Unit Tests

        return GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messaging.Messenger.Default; // Runtime
```

Otherwise one might end up re-inventing the wheel, since in more complex situations where there is a need to test ViewModel communications, you will have to manage Messenger subscribers, message types an so on. Then probably writing unit tests for the messenger mock making sure it works in the same way as the original messenger. There is nothing in the engine of the Messenger that should be different when comparing Runtime and Test executions.

So for testing a factory returns the same instance of the Messenger. Test method subscribes and waits, ViewModel publishes; then Test accepts and exits. Otherwise Test times out and reports an error. I found this approach more "closer to reality" than mocking the messenger and verifying through the mock that the method was called.